# Syntax highlighting in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, emf

Does Eclipse Editor/EMF framework support syntax highlighting? I'm looking to use that in my RCP application. Specifically I am looking for using this for COBOL and JCL.

Comment: You might want to look at [Eclipse xText](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) which uses EMF models and provides lots of support for developing language editors.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I read some of the documentation in the xtext official page. But none of it points to satisfy my requirement. Looks like it is more suited for new language development. could you throw some insight into how this could be useful for my requirement

Comment: Tried out StyledText widget and finally settled in the Eclipse TextEditor component which can be used for syntax highlighting of any language. The XMLEditor template example given in Eclipse IDE was a good starting point

Answer (score 2):

Tried out StyledText widget and finally settled in the Eclipse TextEditor component which can be used for syntax highlighting of any language. The XMLEditor template example given in Eclipse IDE was a good starting point